# C# How to turn an Action of T into awaitable Function of Task of T

Tags: c#, async-await, delegates, func

I'd like to be able to save some methods as actions and their corresponding async counterparts. For that I need to turn them into `Func<Task>`.

I've got this working.

```
public class Class1 {
    Action myAction;
    Func<Task> myFunc;

    public Class1() {
        // for demo purposes I use a local method
        void MyVoidMethod() {
            // some code
        }
        myAction = MyVoidMethod;
        myFunc = () => Task.Factory.StartNew(myAction);
    }

    public async void AnotherMethod() {
        // later in async some method
        await myFunc.Invoke();
    }
}
```

But how do I declare this when I also want to have an optional input parameter for example to report progress in the async Func? I don't get how the syntax works for this.

```
public class Class2 {
    Action<IProgress<bool>> myAction;
    Func<Task<IProgress<bool>>> myFunc;

    public Class2() {
        void MyVoidMethod(IProgress<bool> prog = null) {
            // some code
        }
        myAction = MyVoidMethod;
        // line below gives squiggelies under `myAction`
        myFunc = () => Task.Factory.StartNew(myAction);
    }

    public async void AnotherMethod() {
        // later in async some method
        var prog = new Progress<bool>();
        prog.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => {
            // do something with e
        };
        await myFunc.Invoke(prog);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be confusing `Action<T>`, which takes a `T` as input parameter, with a `Task<T>` which returns a T as result. Besides that, do not declare `async void` methods. Always use `async Task`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the myFunc to take in a Task instead of returning one, you need to define the func to take in the IProgressand return a Task as result.

```
Func<IProgress<bool>, Task> myFunc;
```

Then you need to pass in the progress to the executing method in your lambda

```
this.myFunc = p => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.MyVoidMethod(p))
```

And your AnotherMethod needs to take the Progress in as a parameter

```
public async void AnotherMethod(IProgress<bool> progress)
{
    await this.myFunc.Invoke(progress);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I got things muddled up. Of course I don't want to return a Task of some type; just a Task. 
I've edited my question to correctly show the use of the Progress object and event because `AnotherMethod` doesn't necessarily need those input parameters. 
To add to your answer this line would also work: 
`this.myFunc = p => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.myAction.Invoke(p));`